# How to get data from Cordova's in-App Browser

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm working on authentication for an Ionic 4 app. I'm using the in app browser plugin to login. After successful login an access token is sent back to the client. I can't figure out how to get the token from the In-App Browser to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using events to listen for load start and stop was an awesome idea. I was, however, facing another issue. Google doesn't allow sign in using the In-App Browser and I really needed that. After asking around and looking at similar past issues I came across a Cordova plugin called [BrowserTab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser-tab). This was awesome as it's an instance/Custom Tab from chrome so it worked fine with google sign in. Another problem came up. You can't inject Javascript into BrowserTab and there was no way to programmatically close it once done. I looked around some more and that's when Deeplinks came to mind. I used the [Deeplinks plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks) and passed my access token as a parameter. When the user logs in, the BrowserTab redirects to a Custom URL scheme link for my app with the access token in the URL. Now it works perfectly. I've read somewhere that IOS is getting rid of Custom URL Scheme links. Luckily, it still has support for Universal App Links

Answer (score 2):

You can use an event listener such as :

```
this.browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => { this.checkForToken(event); })
```

Where checkForToken can look at your "event.url" and parse the token to be stored to localStorage or some other method to be used to login with once the in-app browser is closed.

Comment: have you tried your solution? because loadstart event fire when inappbrowser start loading..

Comment: Well end to end there’s a bit more to the entire code, you’d asked how to get the token and this is how that is done. I have used in app browser for oauth, and it works in production, I would like to note that used capacitor and ionic 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction. I've also found that I can run JS code using `executeScript` method. Combining `on('loadstop')` and executeScript has helped me.